# How can I manually configure my IMAP and SMTP servers in Outlook 2016

Tags: email, imap, smtp, microsoft-outlook-2016

Microsoft is trying make it easier for people to configure their email settings in Outlook 2016 but unfortunaletly, they are also making live extremely difficult for users who need a different configuration than the standard one that Outlook guesses/assumes.

For example, if you want to use the SMTP server of a different provider that the IMAP server, and you try to change the settings via "Account Settings" -> "Repair ..." (Yes, don't ask me why they moved it from "Change ..." to "Repair ..."), Outlook will just change (some of) the settings back and then complain that they don't work. Or, if they work, it will just silently change them back without you noticing.

**So how can I manually configure my IMAP and SMTP settings in Outlook 2016 and be treated like someone who knows what they're doing?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To manually change your account settings in Outlook 2016:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to open the "Send & Receive settings". (If the shortcut doesn't work for you, try navigating to a different folder.)
2. Click "Edit" (While "All accounts" is selected)
3. Select your account
4. Click on Account Properties.
5. Here you can edit the server settings at will:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Control Panel > Mail (Outlook 2016) > Email accounts... 
The account setup form is opened similar to the one used in Outlook, but
when you select New... the old window fill be open instead of this new limited which is opened inside Outlook.

This also works when you want to add a new account and you login is different than your email address.

There is no way to specify this (at least I could not find it), The outlook tries to verify the account before saving it. If the authentication fails the account is not saved, so you cannot edit it later on.
In this case Control panel > Mail > etc. helps.